# Activiti creates new Job for timer event

Tags: activiti

We are using **activiti 5.10** and we are noticing a very strange behaviour for activiti timed tasks:

We have a timed task that wakes up every 30 seconds, checks if "work" needs to be done and if so, it does this work and finishes itself. If no work is to be done, it finishes itself.

This all works without any exceptions or "hickups".

**The problem that we have, is that activiti creates new instances of this timed event occasionally. This means that another entry in the table "act_ru_job" is created for this process definition. So instead of one timed task doing the work, we now have two. And after a month we already have more then 100.**

This doesn´t happen every time, sometimes there are two week where nothing happens. There are no exceptions, and the task table (act_ru_task) shows me that there are no tasks waiting for completion.

I know that this is really a strange error, and that it is pretty hard to solve it without any exceptions but maybe someone here has experienced the same or could lead me to an official bug description.

Best regards,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell from your description, but i think that your process instance is completed, so when another process starts it is normal that you will see another job in "act_ru_job" table but linked to the new instance.